# jQuery UI save position of draggable element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Is there any way to save the initial position of draggable element, determine position in the end of drag and return element to initial position after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `stop` event and the `originalPosition` value of the `ui` parameter to get original position.

Once you have the original position - you can move the element to that position using `$(this).animate` with the values of originalPosition

Here is an example of that:

```js
$( ".drag" ).draggable({
  stop: function( event, ui ) {
    console.log(ui.originalPosition)
    $(this).animate(ui.originalPosition)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid red;" class="drag"> Drag Me! </div>
<div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid green;" class="drag"> Drag Me! </div>
```